# Mysql Connect Two Tables (FK) - Database Design

Tags: mysql, database-design

how can I connect the table project_user with the table project_terms in the best way?

- One Project has different Categorys like 1,2,3,4
- The Categorys are stored in the categorys_table
- But one User maybe are assigned only for the Categorys 1,2 and not 3,4
- Should I connect the project_table with the categorys_table too?

how can I solve that in my Database Design?

```
[project_user]
id name
1  Tom

// But User Tom only assigned for the Project_id 1
// and the cat_id 2 in the project_terms table

[project_terms]
project_id (fk) | cat_id (fk)
1               | 2
1               | 3


[categorys_table]
cat_id | catname
2      | Lemon
3      | Apple



[project_table]

project_id | name
1          | FruitsProject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Comment: great schema, is it possible to insert CategoryID 1,2,3,4 belonging to ProjectID 1?

Comment: @ali -- yes. A user can be assigned any sub-set of project-category combination.

Answer (score 1):

No idea if I understood you correctly: One possible approach could be to associate all your users with a project

```
[project_project_user]
project_id  |   user_id
    1              1
```

With this, you have a user assigned to a project.

To be able to check the terms, you could introduce a table that matches terms to users.

```
[project_terms_user]
user_id   |    term_id
    1              2
```

You could also go as fas as leaving out the `[project_project_user]` table since the connection can be established via `[project_terms_user]`. Some queires may be more efficient with the first table available, but the resuls should be the same.